# Using inner join on a specific record?

Tags: mysql

So we have 2 tables

users:

```
id | username | email
1  | testuser | test@test.com
2  | dirk     | test2@test2.com
```

data:

```
id | data         | username
1  | somedata     | dirk
3  | somemoredata | testuser
```

I want to select the username of the data table with the id 3 and then select his email. Which is the nicest way to do this with an inner join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the result by joining your two tables on the `username` column, then you can use a `WHERE` clause to filter for the row with `id = 3`:

```
select d.id, d.username, u.email
from data d
inner join users u
  on d.username = u.username
where d.id = 3;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa5a4/1)